# Make pdf in Jupyter notebook with Russian letters

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, tex

I try to create pdf in Jupyter notebook. It's OK for English letter, but for Russians there is a error:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-4.def)
! Undefined control sequence.
\u-default-1055 #1->\CYRP                   
l.278     П
            ривет, мир!
? 
! Emergency stop.
\u-default-1055 #1->\CYRP                         
l.278     П
            ривет, мир!
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: please show your code, so that we can help you.

Comment: The error occurs for any notebook with russian letters. 
For example for .ipynb file with one Markdowm cell: `Привет, мир!` . 
(this is analogue for `Hello, world!`)

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to "File" - "Print preview".

2) Then print that page with [DoPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/ru/) virtual printer, or analog.

That's it.

But first disable additional margins and headers in  the browser's `about:config` . In Firefox it will be print.print_footer*** and print.printer_PrinterName.print_footer***

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you are affiliated with DoPDF, you should disclose this affiliation. Spam, and things that appear to be spam, are taken _very_ seriously on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hello, S.L. Barth! My relation to the subject can be defined as "user".

Comment: What's your recommendation for me to the future? It's a well-known software, but if needed, I can rewrite the answer using "canonical" Acrobat DС, or even provide [a comprehensive list of virtual printers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_virtual_printer_software). Versatility in action :) Thanks for the style correction, by the way.

Comment: If you're not affiliated with it, it should be OK. I don't think you have to re-write the answer. Just be careful when recommending specific software, especially if it's commercial (as opposed to free/open source).

Answer (score 1):

I found answer here: https://habrahabr.ru/post/279601/ . First convert to `tex`, then make some small changes in code.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and things have changed a lot over the years. Here is a solution that seems to work with fairly recent versions of TexLive Cyrillic fonts, Jupyter Notebook and XeLaTeX.

For "Download as -> PDF via LaTeX (.pdf)" feature Jupyter Notebook runs `jupyter nbconvert` that in turn by default uses XeLaTeX.

NBConvert generates a LaTeX file from a Notebook using templates. The template structure is documented in [base.tex.j2](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/main/share/templates/latex/base.tex.j2). The default template would be called `index.tex.j2`. When NBconvert runs it looks for this file in a list of directories. The first one in the list is `$HOME/.local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/latex`.

Here is a basic template based on LaTeX article class that uses Droid fonts and supports Cyrillic letters.

```
((=- Default to the notebook output style -=))
((*- if not cell_style is defined -*))
    ((* set cell_style = 'style_jupyter.tex.j2' *))
((*- endif -*))

((=- Inherit from the specified cell style. -=))
((* extends cell_style *))


%===============================================================================
% Latex Article
%===============================================================================

((*- block docclass -*))
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

((*- endblock docclass -*))

((*- block packages -*))
((( super() )))
\usepackage{droid}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{DroidSerif}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{DroidSansMono}
\AtBeginDocument{
\setmainfont{DroidSerif-Regular.ttf}
\setsansfont{DroidSans.ttf}
\setmonofont{DroidSansMono.ttf}
}

((*- endblock packages -*))
```

Create a file `index.tex.j2` in the `$HOME/.local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/latex` directory and copy the text above into this file.

The resulting PDF file seems to render Cyrillics correctly.

[image: screenshot of a page from the resulting PDF file]